# SQL Server / How to sort a duration from two datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering if it's possible to sort a duration from two datetime. For example, I want the duration between `'2019-12-09 09:00:00'` and `'2019-12-09 15:00:00'`.

A simple subtraction could work?

Comment: You can use DATEDIFF fro your purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DATEDIFF fro your purpose. based on your requirement, you can define the duration for

```
year, yyyy, yy = Year
quarter, qq, q = Quarter
month, mm, m = month
dayofyear = Day of the year
day, dd, y = Day
week, ww, wk = Week
weekday, dw, w = Weekday
hour, hh = hour
minute, mi, n = Minute
second, ss, s = Second
millisecond, ms = Millisecond
```

Script-

```
WITH your_table(st_date,end_date)
AS
(
    SELECT '20190102', '20190103' UNION ALL
    SELECT '20190102', '20190105'
)

SELECT st_date,end_date,
DATEDIFF(DD,st_date,end_date) 
FROM your_table
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(DD,st_date,end_date) DESC
```

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e653c22bf966f232aa8f14b8dc98681a)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sqlserver you can use this function:

```
-- as minute
select datediff(minute,'2019-12-09 09:00:00','2019-12-09 15:00:00')

-- as hour
select datediff(hour,'2019-12-09 09:00:00','2019-12-09 15:00:00')
```

Answer (score 1):

Output will give duration output in Hr:Min format

```
SELECT CONCAT(datediff(HH,'2019-12-09 09:00:00','2019-12-09 15:00:00'),':', DATEDIFF(Minute,'2019-12-09 09:00:00','2019-12-09 15:30:00')%60)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)**

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime

SELECT @StartDate = '2019-12-09 09:00:00' ,@EndDate='2019-12-09 15:00:00'

SELECT convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, @startDate, @EndDate)/3600)+':'+convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, @startDate, @EndDate)%3600/60)+':'+convert(varchar(5),(DateDiff(s, @startDate, @EndDate)%60)) as [hh:mm:ss]
```

> Output looks like
>
> ```
> hh:mm:ss
> 6:0:0
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The unambiguous way to write this is (i.e. increase the 2nd date by 1 and make it <)

```
select * 
from xxx 
where dates >= '20191026'
  and dates <  '20191028'
```

If you're using SQL Server 2008 or above, you can safety CAST as DATE while retaining SARGability, e.g.

```
select * 
from xxx 
where CAST(dates as DATE) between '20191026' and '20191027'
```

This explicitly tells SQL Server that you are only interested in the DATE portion of the dates column for comparison against the BETWEEN range.